# IOS 7 : didAddAnnotationViews not response to addAnnotation

Tags: ios7, mapkit

I am trying to add annotations into my **MKMapView** and I want to set annotations to be clickable.(clickable feature I did in **didAddAnnotationViews**.)

Actually, this feature is working fine for IOS 6, but not working for IOS 7. I added a simple NSLog print statement in my **didAddAnnotationViews** method, and I found **didAddAnnotationViews**  not response to **addAnnotaion** properly. I thought **didAddAnnotationViews**  will be called each time in response to **addAnnotaion** . When I added several annotations only one log statement print, which means **didAddAnnotationViews** only execute once I think.

I'm using **MapKit, MKMapView** and this issue only occur in IOS 7. Can anyone give me a idea how to fix or find the reason why didAddAnnotationViews not working properly?

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{    
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [views objectAtIndex:0];
    MapViewAnnotation *annotation=annotationView.annotation;
    NSLog(@"<==========didAddAnnotationViews=============> %@",annotation.title);

    annotationView.canShowCallout=YES;
    if(annotation.subtitle==nil){
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = nil;
    }else{
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(annotation.coordinate, 11000, 11000);
        [mv setRegion:region animated:YES];
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you tried?

Comment: You should be setting canShowCallout and rightCalloutAccessoryView in the viewForAnnotation delegate method -- not in didAddAnnotationViews.    You can leave the setRegion in there though that may result in strange behavior depending on how the annotations are being added.  Regardless of iOS version, do not make rigid assumptions about when the delegate methods will be called by the map view.

Comment: Thank you Anna Karenina, I solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method signature implies that multiple annotation views are given at the same time:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views;
```

Try logging the array of views with:

```
NSLog(@"%@", views);
```

If you are lucky, you'll see all your annotations. Iterate over them instead of only looking at the first object at index 0.